# Python variable assignment in numpy

Tags: python, numpy, variables

```
np.put(press,np.squeeze(np.where(press >= psfc))[1:],np.nan)
    missing = np.logical_or(np.logical_or(np.isnan(press),np.isnan(qhum)),np.logical_or(np.isnan(tmp_k),np.isnan(hgt)))
allmissing = np.zeros(nlev,dtype = 'float32')
allmissing[:] = np.nan
tmp_k = tmp_k[np.logical_not(np.isnan(np.where(missing,np.nan,tmp_k)))]
allmissing[:len(tmp_k)] = tmp_k
tmp_k = allmissing
qhum = qhum[np.logical_not(np.isnan(np.where(missing,np.nan,qhum)))]
allmissing[:len(qhum)] = qhum
qhum = allmissing
```

In the above code when value of qhum is changed also the value of tmp_k is changing. When allmissing variable is reassigned by changing its value to qhum initial assignment is also changing. i,e tmp_k and qhum both are having same values... Why is this happening?

```
import numpy as np
press_in = [98100,97400,95300,94100]
tmp_in = [285.6,289,290.4,290]
qhum_in = [0.0087998267,0.0089221532,0.0095515558,0.0080244699]
psfc = 980.085*1e2
q2m = 0.00907988
t2m = 285.615
nlev = 4 + 1 
press = np.zeros(nlev,dtype = 'float32')
press[:] = np.nan
press[1:] = press_in
tmp_k = np.zeros(nlev,dtype = 'float32')
tmp_k[:] = np.nan
tmp_k[1:]  =  tmp_in
qhum = np.zeros(nlev,dtype = 'float32')
qhum[:] = np.nan
qhum[1:]  =  qhum_in
tmp_k[0]   =  t2m
hgt  [0]   =  h2m
qhum [0]   =  q2m
press[0]   =  psfc

np.put(press,np.squeeze(np.where(press >= psfc))[1:],np.nan)
missing = np.logical_or(np.logical_or(np.isnan(press),np.isnan(qhum)),np.logical_or(np.isnan(tmp_k),np.isnan(hgt)))
allmissing = np.zeros(nlev,dtype = 'float32')
allmissing[:] = np.nan
tmp_k = tmp_k[np.logical_not(np.isnan(np.where(missing,np.nan,tmp_k)))]
allmissing[:len(tmp_k)] = tmp_k
tmp_k = allmissing
qhum = qhum[np.logical_not(np.isnan(np.where(missing,np.nan,qhum)))]
allmissing[:len(qhum)] = qhum
qhum = allmissing
```

above is an [mcve](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)

Comment: What is the question?

Comment: In th question i posted when I assign the value of 'allmissing' after changing it to qhum. The initial assignment to tmp_k is also changing. meaning tmp_k and qhum both are having same values

Comment: Please provide a [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) that includes a short sample dataset. Doing that may already help you figure out what is happening.

Comment: Yes assigning `x =y` means both variables point to the same object.  That is basic python. Do you want a copy instead?

Comment: yes it worked fine when i used np.copy(). Thank you!